# Alternate ways to sendKeys in Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

Below is the `HTML` for a text field:

```
<input class=" input" maxlength="255" type="text" aria-describedby="" placeholder="" id="4769:0" data-aura-rendered-by="4773:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="53">
```

I have written below code to type the 'text' in the field

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/input[starts-with(@id,'4') and @class=' input' and @type='text' and @placeholder='']")).sendKeys("text");
```

It is identifying the field but not typing the text?

Comment: Below is the HTML : <input class=" input" maxlength="255" type="text" aria-describedby="" placeholder="" id="4769:0" data-aura-rendered-by="4773:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="53">

Comment: In which way have you verified that it is identifying the right field ?

Comment: @SantiBailors I tried in the Console

Comment: I was asking that to the OP, in response to his/her "_It is identifying the field but not typing the text?_".

Comment: But now the OP's name changed to Ritika, so I guess it's always you, so, in response to your "_I tried in the Console_": I hope you are not trying to be funny. What console, what did you enter in that console, what output you got, what in it indicated to you that it is identifying the right field ?

Comment: are you sure this xpath is not returning multiple elements?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [`JavaScriptExecutor`](http://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html):

```
WebElement inputField =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/input[starts-with(@id,'4') and @class=' input' and @type='text' and @placeholder='']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='text';", inputField);
```

Comment: Thanks ! But its not working, its even not throwing any error.

Comment: Is it possible to share page `URL`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your locator strategy is a problem:

```
.//div/input[starts-with(@id,'4') and @class=' input' and @type='text' and @placeholder='']
```

`.` -> are we finding any child element?
`starts-with(@id,'4')` -> can return multiple elements

and same is for other 'and' conditions in your xpath.

Try some other xpath taking following-sibling/preceding.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the textbox needs to be clicked in order to send the value. In my case, before use sendkeys, i click over the textbox:

```
WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.id("textbox_id"));
text.click();
text.sendKeys("Value");
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to click on that field before send text.

try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/input[starts-with(@id,'4') and @class=' input' and @type='text' and @placeholder='']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/input[starts-with(@id,'4') and @class=' input' and @type='text' and @placeholder='']")).sendKeys("text");
```

Comment: No, there is no need to click the field before sending text to it.

Comment: @soumyakalage You don't need to click the field. But the fact that it's not clickable probably means that you cannot type in it, which would be the reason why it doesn't receive the keys you send to it. You should add this information to the question.

Comment: @SantiBailors Some fields are visible only after clicking on the above field. I need to click on that field. How shall I do it? Can you please help.

Comment: @soumyakalage The help given on SO is not intended for a single person but also for anyone who reads the questions and answers later. Your chances of getting help increase if you don't do "please help" and if you make the situation as clear as possible, which so far is not. Your "_Some fields are visible only after clicking on the above field_" sounds very relevant to your problem but also very unclear. My suggestion is to edit your question to minimize the need for people to guess. Ask yourself what info you'd need if you had to help someone with that problem. F.ex. _some fields_ which ?